# SSH Public Key for user without home directory

Tags: macos, ssh, rsa, osx-leopard

I'm running a Mac OS X Leopard Server and I created a new user without designating a home directory for that user. Is it possible to have that user authenticate using a Public Key?

I know that when a user **does** have a home directory it goes in to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I don't want to create a home directory for this user because my understanding is it would then allow them to login if given physical access.

**UPDATE:** I need to allow this user to do a Secure FTP connection only. Setting the Login Shell to `/bin/false/` will prevent them from connecting remotely as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or where it is located on your machine and change the `AuthorizedKeysFile` setting.

The docs say:

```
 AuthorizedKeysFile
         Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used
         for user authentication.  AuthorizedKeysFile may contain tokens of
         the form %T which are substituted during connection setup.  The fol-
         lowing tokens are defined: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %h is
         replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and
         %u is replaced by the username of that user.  After expansion,
         AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one relative
         to the user's home directory.  The default is
         ``.ssh/authorized_keys''.
```

But why do you have users (that can login) without a home?

Comment: I want them to be able to SFTP in to a folder that I designated. I chrooted SFTP to a subfolder.

Comment: That's why in my case: I have a limited user for tunneling(proxing) from server to https sites, he doesn't need permission to access any files and directories and ssh commands  and no home is required for him. I want to add my public key to access/test this user proxy without password, also using pubkey is more secure for user too. Your answer require to allow user to have at least one file or have home directory so not solved what I was looking for in my case.